# Trying to upload a file from HTML form to server via AJAX and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've researched many posts about this and am still experiencing trouble, which is why I decided to post a question about it.

I have an html form with a file input:

```
<form id='AddFile' action='AddFile.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>

    <input type='file' id='fileAdd' name='fileAdd'>

    Friendly Name: <input type='text' id='friendlyname-Add'>

</form>
```

I have some JavaScript that prepares the file for upload:

```
var form = $('AddFile')[0];
var formData = new FormData(form);

$.ajax({

      url: "AddFile.php",
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      cache: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data){

          alert("file uploaded!");

     ...
```

and PHP that handles the data:

```
<?php

$uploaddir = 'path';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['fileAdd']['name']);
echo $uploadfile;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileAdd']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {

    ...

}else{

...

}

?>
```

Comment: For one thing, `$uploaddir = 'path';` there's no trailing slash for it and your PHP is translating that as `folderFILE.jpg` rather than the intended `folder/FILE.jpg`. That's IF that's your real declaration for it.

Comment: thanks for the feedback; I found out I accidentally saved the file in a different folder so the AJAX reference was empty; fixed it and it works now!

Answer (score 0):

Typo:

```
var form = $('AddFile')[0];
              ^---no #
```

without a `#` or `.`, jquery is looking for a `<AddFile>` tag, which obviously doesn't exist.

If you had even minimal error handling on the PHP code, you'd have seen that no upload was being performed. There's a `['error']` parameter in $_FILES for a reason:

```
if($_FILES['fileAdd']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['fileAdd']['error']);
}
```

Comment: I think both our buttons have been set to [*ignore...*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38061249/trying-to-upload-a-file-from-html-form-to-server-via-ajax-and-php#comment63561500_38061249)

Comment: thanks for the feedback; I added a #; also, I found out I accidentally saved the file in a different folder so the AJAX reference was empty; fixed it and it works now!